# R List and Vector Dilemma

Tags: r

I have a spec that tells me that I need to have variable `C` be a list with elements that are character vectors.

So, I tried

```
C = list()
vector = c("dsdas", "dsadsda", "dsdasdasdasdada")
C[1] = vector
```

then I get the `warning : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

but notice that `C` only contains 1 element at index 1 which is `"dsdas"`

However, this will work.

```
C = list()
vector = list(c("dsdas", "dsadsda", "dsdasdasdasdada"))
C[1] = vector
```

What are my options if my specs say that I need to have a character vector as opposed to a list, and why is `C` behaving like this? I thought that a list could hold any length character vectors?

Comment: What is using this list? Maybe all you need to know is that to get one of the vectors out, you need to use double brackets. I.e. don't use `C[1]`, but `C[[1]]` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lists` can behave as you wish, however you are being caught by the `[` / `[[` trap (or more specifically the `[<-`/`[[<-` trap.

Use `[[` to extract (and `[[<-` to append or replace single elements  within a list

Use `[` to extract and `[<-` to append or replace *multiple* elements within a list

In your case you are trying to assign to   single element `C[[1]]`

So

```
C[[1]] <- vector
```

If you want to assign using `[<-`  in this case I would reccommend not doing so.

If you really feel you want to do so you can pass a `list` (as `[<` expects a list because `C` is a list)

```
C[1] <- list(vector)
```